# Access denied when trying to run django-admin startproject

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am new to django and I tried to create a project with `django-admin startproject` command. The tutorial I was referring to had no errors while going through this command but I get the following error. The tutorial and I are not doing it in any virtual environment. Though this error comes, the files and folder are created in the directory I am working in, how should I solve this error?

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\runpy.py", line 87, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\django-admin.exe_main_.py", line 7, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\__init_.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\__init_.py", line 440, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
self.execute(\*args, \*\*cmd_options)
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\base.py", line 448, in execute
output = self.handle(\*args, \*\*options)
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\commands\\startproject.py", line 21, in handle    super().handle("project", project_name, target, \*\*options)
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\templates.py", line 225, in handle
run_formatters(\[top_dir\])
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\utils.py", line 165, in run_formatters  
subprocess.run(
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
with Popen(\*popenargs, \*\*kwargs) as process:
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
self.\_execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 1416, in \_execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = \_winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied
```

Comment: Which directory are you working in?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please be sure to read the ["How do I ask good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. The biggest issue with this post is that the heading "Django-admin startproject" is not helpful for other people searching for questions. Please consider changing it to "Access denied when trying to run django-admin startproject". That being said, you shouldn't need to create a virtual environment, rather its just recommended. Make sure that django is installed -> `pip show django` should do that.

Comment: First do > pip install django - in terminal. Then, do > django-admin startproject <projectname>. Open command prompt as adminstrator.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: opening powershell as adminstrator in my working directory has solved the problem. Thank you @SivaSankar